# How I can multiply the fourth one from each row in the text file

Tags: python

- 2, 1, 2, 3, **4**, 15, 14, 29, 64168.0, 1

  2, 1, 2, 3, **6**, 15, 14, 29, 64168.0, 1

  2, 1, 2, 3, **8**, 15, 14, 29, 64168.0, 1

I wanna multiply this item

```
elif menu == 4:
    fin = open("data.txt", "r")
    i = 0
    n = 0
    freeday = fin.read[i][9]
    i = i + 1

    print freeday
# 45 saatten fazla calısma yasası.......(n)
elif menu == 5:
    fin = open("data.txt", "r")
    for line in fin:
        totalweekdayshour = [5]
        totalweekendhour = [6]
    if totalweekdayshour + totalweekendhour >= 45:

        print ("workers must be work 45 h")

    else:
        print ("no problem")
    fin.close`
```

Comment: I want to multiply the fourth one from each row in the text file

Comment: use a global var of 1 and multiply it by each line in the fourth index

Answer (score 1):

```
column_no=4
product=1
with open('data.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for line in content:
        line_list=line.strip().split(', ')
        product*=int(line_list[column_no-1]) #indexing starts from 0
print(product)
```